# Finding average of a dictionary with loop

Tags: python, dictionary, average

```
stock={'meat':100,'fish':100,'bread':100, 'milk':100,'chips':100, 'apple':100,'orange':100, 'rice':100,'honey':100,'lemon':100}

totalstock = 0
totalitem=0
for item, value in stock.items():
    totalitem += value
    totalstock += value
    average = totalstock/totalitem

    print("average stock level :",average)
```

hi guys , i have been trying to calculate the sum of this dictionary and finding its average however i have some trouble with my codes, above are my codes.

My desired output would be "average stock level" : 100

thanks alot in advance i will appreciate any help i can get

Comment: `totalitem +=1` in the for loop will give you the desired result. As it is, you're dividing two equal numbers, forcing the average to always be one

Comment: You can avoid for-loop: `print(f'average stock level: {np.mean(list(stock.values()))}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are several thing wrong here.

The total stock and the loop seems ok, but nothing else.

```
totalstock = 0
for value in stock.values():
    totalstock += value

average = totalstock/len(stock)

print("average stock level :",average)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without a loop:

```
stock={'meat':100,'fish':100,'bread':100, 'milk':100,'chips':100, 'apple':100,'orange':100, 'rice':100,'honey':100,'lemon':100}
_avgStock = int(sum(stock.values())/len(stock))  # sum up all values divide by amount of items.
print("Avg is: %s" % _avgStock)
```

Output:

```
Avg is: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `statistics` module,

```
from statistics import mean

print(f"Avg is : {mean(stock.values())}")

Avg is : 100
```